# Linear gradients library

Tags: apache-flex, gradient

Is there a place online where I can find like 16 linear gradients that match good with each other? I need them for a chart of mine and the ones generated (by Flex) aren't good enough.

So, I'm kind off searching for a library of gradients (linear in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [colourlovers](http://www.colourlovers.com) and [kuler](http://www.kuler.com) they're both online colour theme generators, you'll have to take the generated themes and turn them into gradients on your own, but that shouldn't be that hard.